# Google Script fails to upload file to Google Drive via iOS

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Site with an embedded Google Script that allows a user to upload a photo.  After validating that the photo is a MIME image type and smaller than 3MB, I copy it to a folder in my Google Drive.

This functionality works perfectly from my Mac laptop (both Chrome and Safari) and my Android phone (Chrome), but when I try it from my iPad (both Chrome and Safari), I get:

NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 500.

I'd thought that the error was in my Code.gs, but I've stripped my processForm() code down to `return true`, and it still throws this error.  So now I think the error is happening in this call in my HTML file:

```
      google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(reportSuccess).withFailureHandler(reportFailure)
    .processForm(formData);
```

I tried wrapping this code in console.log() calls, but then I realized that iOS doesn't let me see the console. :P

Somehow the "NetworkError" exception is thrown in this call; it's then caught and reported by the failure handler `reportFailure`.

Again, this script *works* on my Mac laptop and my Android phone, just not on my iPad (or a colleague's iPhone).

Does anyone have any ideas about (a) what might be the root cause of this problem in the interaction between Google Script and iOS's networking layer and/or (b) how I might work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is perfectly working on your browser from Mac laptop, it maybe that Apple does not yet allow Google App Scripts to run on these devices(iphone & ipad). I found a note on [iOS Quickstart for App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/ios) that maybe hinting at this:

> Note: The application does not conform with Apple's iOS Human
>   Interface Guidelines. It is intended only to illustrate the basic
>   concepts and steps needed to begin working with the Google Apps Script
>   Execution API.

Comment: I don't think the snippet you've posted means that; instead, I read it as just a warning to folks not to submit an app built on that sample code to the App Store and expect it to pass.  (The Human Interface Guidelines are some of the rules that apps must comply with to be published on the App Store.)
Nonetheless, it could certainly be the case that Apple doesn't play nicely with Google Script (yet?).

Comment: As it is not working in iPhone and iPad, it only means it is not supported as of now. The main proof is that it works well on your Macbook which is an Apple product.

Comment: Well, it doesn't even *necessarily* mean that it isn't supported right now.  It could be that there's some quirky workaround that I haven't found yet.  But I agree that it definitely works on at least my Apple laptop. :)  I should have written "iOS" instead of "Apple" above.